# Make all pre-exisiting <b> and <i> to be <strong> and <em> after migration from rtehtmlarea in TYPO3 7.6 to rte_ckeditor in 8.7

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typoscript, tsconfig, typo3-8.x

## The Goal

We need all `<b>` and `<i>` tags that come from one of TYPO3's rich text editor fields to be `<strong>` and `<em>`.

## A Manual Solution (but we need an automated solution)

We can open up a content element that has the wrong tags and just click save and TYPO3 updates the tags. BUT we have maybe 100k content elements to sort through so we need a more automated solution.

## The Problem

We have migrated a website from TYPO3 CMS 7.6 to 8.7. Along with that upgrade we are new using `rte_ckeditor` instead of `rtehtmlarea`. Any new content created by `rte_ckeditor` uses the correct tags, but anything that was originally created in `rtehtmlarea` before the migration continues to use `<b>` and `<i>` tags since it's saved in the database that way.

---

**Soooooooo, how can we update our database to use only `<strong>` and `<em>`  for all rich text editor fields ???**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is no technical solution but a general description which options exist to solve the problem with respect to the large amount of data**

For CKEditor I'd recommend an individual plugin that is replacing tags each time a content-element is opened for editing.
Apart from that I'd recommend an output-parser that can be included in the page-setup or as extension of TYPO3 to rewrite undesired tags in favor of their desired replacements.

Alternatively the whole database can be read by an individual PHP-script / TYPO3-extension to replace all tags once. This could be done on production-server with restricted amount of rewrites per minute / hour.
Another option is to replace all tags in an database-export with any kind of tool or program and replace the old data then with the altered data in the database.